# Wix 32 and 64 Bit Components within one 32 Bit MSI

Tags: x86, wix, 64-bit, installation

I tried for several hours to create an 32-bit installer which integrated 32 Bit and 64 Bit Versions of an exe File. But it seems like the 64-Bit exe is never integrated into the installer.

It should be possible to integrate both versions within one installer or not? If both use the same paths and everything. I only want that based on a condition the 32-Bit or the 64-Bit Version is installed.

The wix file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

…

```
<Product Id="0E69C1BC-D9CD-4886-83D6-6240AEDC4D4F" Name="!(loc.ApplicationName)" Language="!(loc.Language)" Version="$(var.VersionNumber)" Manufacturer="!(loc.ManufacturerFullName)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
   …

  <Property Id="OFFICEVERSION">
    <RegistrySearch Id="OfficeVersion"
                    Root="HKCR"
                    Key="Outlook.Application\CurVer"
                  Type="raw" />
  </Property>

<Property Id="Office64" Value="no"/>

…
```

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
```

…

```
      <!-- 32-Bit -->
      <Component Id="ml.32" Guid="{8739FAD5-28ED-4F19-B25A-8CC05BA87174}"  >
        <File Source="$(var.ProjectDir)..\build\x86\ml.exe" Id="mlExe" KeyPath="yes"/>
         <Condition><![CDATA[NOT Office64]]></Condition>
      </Component>

      <!-- 64-Bit -->
      <Component Id="ml.64" Guid="{8B6345EE-689D-4E13-882D-CF5B4F97252A}" >
        <File Source="$(var.ProjectDir)..\build\x64\ml.exe" Id="mlExe64" KeyPath="yes" />
       <Condition><![CDATA[Office64]]></Condition>
      </Component>

      …

    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Anbody has an idea on that ?

Comment: Funny, I would expect this to install the second component. (The value `no` is evaluated as true, as it is not empty.) Are you certain you're identifying the files correctly, and that the verbose log agrees?

Comment: The Office64 Variable is set by some custom action

Comment: Properties with any lower case letters are considered private, and their values are not shared from the UI sequence to Execute sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[32-bit packages do not support 64-bit components.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367425(v=vs.85).aspx) To install 64-bit components, you must use a [64-bit package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: But how the installer knows it's a 64-Bit exe File? 

So the only option is two installers?

Comment: If a 64-bit file is going to a 32-bit directory, you can have one installer. Otherwise, you need two.

Comment: Yes. The 64-Bit File can be installed within the 32-Bit directory. The Question for me is then. What's wrong with the installer above?

Comment: There is a known hack around this. :)